# Triggering schedule job only once in multiple node environment

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, docker-swarm

I am using Docker swarm mode to run multiple instances of Java (Spring Boot) application, and I would like to run schedule job twice a day but it needs to be triggered only by one instance of application.

Is there any mechanism to configure Spring Boot application and Docker swarm to run that scheduled task just once?

I've seen in Jive property:

```
<property name="allNodes" value="false"/>
```

and now I am wondering if I can do some similar thing on my infrastructure.

Application instances are in same network, so I suppose network discovery wouldn't be the problem.

Comment: not sure about docker swarm, But I have achieved this in couple of other ways. 1. By obtaining a lock on a database table. 2. using zookeeper 3, Using distributed lock

Comment: Do you have zookeeper setup?

Comment: We do not have zookeeper, and also we do not have database in this application (it is only calculating certain things). I would like to solve it only with Spring and Docker if possible, other way we will have to use some alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create one node as master node and the scheduled job will run only in master node.On failure other node will promoted and become master so eligible for runing the job.

Or you can created a distributed lock(Hazelcast support distributed lock).Every node will call tryLock().The node wins will allow to run the job.

Comment: We have 5 replicas of application and none of it is master currently. Maybe to try with master node and later to introduce Hazelcast (it is planned for future). Thanks for the answer!